# how to Tryparse Numbers from Text file like ascii art with c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, ascii-art

how can i get the numbers that are coded in a ascii art with sticks?

the numberss are in a txt file und it contains this: 
[image: Txt file source]

I must get the nubmers that are drown with stick.

the first step is to get 4 line and than to controll it with an Alphabet.

i get the text in a string[]

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("SourceFile.txt");
```

[image: String from File]

the first 4 line are up to lines[3]. 
how can i controll the different line in the same position? 
it is like a 2d Array or i must do something else?

Comment: Every number has its unique pattern no? you could count how many times there is a space in lines[0] and see like that how many numbers there are in the first line. Take then lines 0 to 4 to form the numbers and count again with 5

Comment: since you know how many numbers there are, you can check for each pattern

Comment: @SamY yes, every number has its unique pattern. How can i do your logik in Code? (to count and controll with the pattern?)

Comment: you need to check the exact code, but something like lines[0].split(" ").length is how many numbers there are in row 1
after you split it you have to check one pattern after the other, so if the first pattern of [0] is "---" then check if the first of [1] is a "/", if not then check if it is "_|" and so on

Comment: for the \t you'll need to do a second split

Comment: so i get 4 entries here: string[] split = lines[0].Split(new[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
the /t can i also delete from the file, in the test i can also do that to make it me easier

Comment: you should get 4 entrys for each line in the row. so like that. It's not perfect, but you are a genius. You'll come up with something ;P

Comment: i have a problem, with the Split and delete the white entries, i get for the number 4 two entries (I I) ;(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88188/discussion-between-samy-and-almir-m).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need an object that stores the pattern and metrics of a symbol(number in your case). Also this object has a method for recognizing its pattern in the given array:

```
public class AsciiNumber
{
    private readonly char[][] _data;

    public AsciiNumber(char character, char[][] data)
    {
        this._data = data;
        this.Character = character;
    }

    public char Character
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public int Width
    {
        get
        {
            return this._data[0].Length;
        }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get
        {
            return this._data.Length;
        }
    }

    public bool Match(string[] source, int startRow, int startColumn)
    {
        if (startRow + this.Height > source.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (var i = startRow; i < startRow + this.Height; i++)
        { 
            var row = source[i];
            if (startColumn + this.Width > row.Length)
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (var j = startColumn; j < startColumn + this.Width; j++)
            {
                if (this._data[i - startRow][j - startColumn] != row[j])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you may create something like alphabet you deal with (I used only numbers 1 and 3):

```
public static class Alphabet
{
    private static readonly AsciiNumber Number1 = new AsciiNumber('1', new[]{
        new []{'|'},
        new []{'|'},
        new []{'|'},
        new []{'|'},
    });

    private static readonly AsciiNumber Number3 = new AsciiNumber('3', new[]{
        new []{'-','-','-'},
        new []{' ',' ','/'},
        new []{' ',' ','\\'},
        new []{'-','-','-'},
    });

    public static readonly IEnumerable<AsciiNumber> All = new[] { Number1, Number3 };
}
```

Assuming that numbers in your source file have permament and equal height you may try code like this:

```
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("SourceFile.txt");
        var lineHeight = 4;

        var text = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i += lineHeight)
        {
            var j = 0;
            while (j < lines[i].Length)
            {
                var match = Alphabet.All.FirstOrDefault(character => character.Match(lines, i, j));
                if (match != null)
                {
                    text.Append(match.Character);
                    j += match.Width;
                }
                else
                {
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Recognized numbers: {0}", text.ToString());
```

N.B. If line height changes over the file you have to improve the code above.

Comment: Have you added other numbers to the Alphabet? Does a number have fixed height of 4? Do you understand what my code does? Though it works perfectly with my test input, it may fail with your input. Use the debugger to understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose we have this text and we want to parse the numbers in it:

```
---       ---      |    |  |     -----   
 /         _|      |    |__|     |___    
 \        |        |       |         |   
--        ---      |       |     ____|
```

First of all, we should remove any unnecessary white-space (or tab, if present) and put a separator char (e.g. `$`) between the numbers, obtaining something similar to this:

```
$---$---$|$|  |$-----$
$ / $ _|$|$|__|$|___ $
$ \ $|  $|$   |$    |$
$-- $---$|$   |$____|$
```

Now we should call the `Split` function on each line of the text, using `$` as separator, and then compare the results with an alphabet.

Let's see how to do this with code. Given the text to parse `string[] lines`, we'll create an extension method to remove unnecessary white-spaces and put a `separator` char/string instead:

```
public static class StringHelperClass
{
    // Extension method to remove any unnecessary white-space and put a separator char instead.
    public static string[] ReplaceSpacesWithSeparator(this string[] text, string separator)
    {
        // Create an array of StringBuilder, one for every line in the text.
        StringBuilder[] stringBuilders = new StringBuilder[text.Length];

        // Initialize stringBuilders.
        for (int n = 0; n < text.Length; n++)
            stringBuilders[n] = new StringBuilder().Append(separator);

        // Get shortest line in the text, in order to avoid Out Of Range Exception.
        int shorterstLine = text.Min(line => line.Length);

        // Temporary variables.
        int lastSeparatorIndex = 0;
        bool previousCharWasSpace = false;

        // Start processing the text, char after char.
        for (int n = 0; n < shorterstLine; ++n)
        {
            // Look for white-spaces on the same position on
            // all the lines of the text.
            if (text.All(line => line[n] == ' '))
            {
                // Go to next char if previous char was also a white-space,
                // or if this is the first white-space char of the text.
                if (previousCharWasSpace || n == 0)
                {
                    previousCharWasSpace = true;
                    lastSeparatorIndex = n + 1;
                    continue;
                }
                previousCharWasSpace = true;

                // Append non white-space chars to the StringBuilder
                // of each line, for later use.
                for (int i = lastSeparatorIndex; i < n; ++i)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < text.Length; j++)
                        stringBuilders[j].Append(text[j][i]);
                }

                // Append separator char.
                for (int j = 0; j < text.Length; j++)
                    stringBuilders[j].Append(separator);

                lastSeparatorIndex = n + 1;
            }
            else
                previousCharWasSpace = false;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < text.Length; j++)
            text[j] = stringBuilders[j].ToString();

        // Return formatted text.
        return text;
    }
}
```

Then, in the `Main` method, we'll use:

```
lines = lines.ReplaceSpacesWithSeparator("$");
```

and

```
ASCIINumbersParser parser = new ASCIINumbersParser(lines, "$");
```

where `ASCIINumbersParser` is this class:

```
public class ASCIINumbersParser
{
    // Will store a list of all the possible numbers
    // found in the text.
    public List<string[]> CandidatesList { get; }

    public ASCIINumbersParser(string[] text, string separator)
    {
        CandidatesList = new List<string[]>();

        string[][] candidates = new string[text.Length][];

        for (int n = 0; n < text.Length; ++n)
        {
            // Split each line in the text, using the separator char/string.
            candidates[n] =
                text[n].Split(new[] { separator }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }

        // Put the strings in such a way that each CandidateList item
        // contains only one possible number found in the text.
        for (int i = 0; i < candidates[0].Length; ++i)
            CandidatesList.Add(candidates.Select(c => c[i]).ToArray());
    }
}
```

At this point, we will use the following class to generate an ASCII art representation of some numbers and to compare the result with our original string (in `Main`):

```
public static class ASCIINumberHelper
{
    // Get an ASCII art representation of a number.
    public static string[] GetASCIIRepresentationForNumber(int number)
    {
        switch (number)
        {
            case 1:
                return new[]
                {
                    "|",
                    "|",
                    "|",
                    "|"
                };
            case 2:
                return new[]
                {
                    "---",
                    " _|",
                    "|  ",
                    "---"
                };
            case 3:
                return new[]
                {
                    "---",
                    " / ",
                   @" \ ",
                    "-- "
                };
            case 4:
                return new[]
                {
                    "|  |",
                    "|__|",
                    "   |",
                    "   |"
                };
            case 5:
                return new[]
                {
                    "-----",
                    "|___ ",
                    "    |",
                    "____|"
                };
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    // See if two numbers represented as ASCII art are equal.
    public static bool ASCIIRepresentationMatch(string[] number1, string[] number2)
    {
        // Return false if the any of the two numbers is null
        // or their lenght is different.

        // if (number1 == null || number2 == null)
        //     return false;
        // if (number1.Length != number2.Length)
        //     return false;

        if (number1?.Length != number2?.Length)
            return false;

        try
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < number1.Length; ++n)
            {
                if (number1[n].CompareTo(number2[n]) != 0)
                    return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

In the end, the `Main` function will look like this:

```
static void Main()
    {
        string ASCIIString = @"
            ---       ---      |    |  |     -----   
             /         _|      |    |__|     |___    
             \        |        |       |         |   
            --        ---      |       |     ____|  ";

        string[] lines =
            ASCIIString.Split(new[] {"\n","\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        lines = lines.ReplaceSpacesWithSeparator("$");

        ASCIINumbersParser parser = new ASCIINumbersParser(lines, "$");

        // Try to find all numbers contained in the ASCII string
        foreach (string[] candidate in parser.CandidatesList)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                string[] num = ASCIINumberHelper.GetASCIIRepresentationForNumber(i);
                if (ASCIINumberHelper.ASCIIRepresentationMatch(num, candidate))
                    Console.WriteLine("Number {0} was found in the string.", i);
            }
        }
    }

    // Expected output:
    // Number 3 was found in the string.
    // Number 2 was found in the string.
    // Number 1 was found in the string.
    // Number 4 was found in the string.
    // Number 5 was found in the string.
```

[Here](http://gist.github.com/ClaudiuGeorgiu/de1da85e5e8213cf9a20) you can find the full code.

Answer (score 0):

1. I created all the models and saved them in the Dictionary.
2. I will create the directories for development
   C:\temp\Validate    C:\temp\Referenz   C:\temp\Extract
3. In Dir Reference, a file will be created for each Model in the Dictionary.
4. I read all the lines, and save them in a string [].
   Encoding I will do it personally from string [] to char [] []. After this operation we will have in Dir Validate the MyEncoding.txt file, containing the New Number List.
   From the previous list all "Char.Empty" (\ t) were converted to char null '\ 0'.
5. As long as I go through the list from left to right column by column,
6. I extract the characters from the List, depending on the width of the Model in the Dictionary (ex NumberOne has width 2, NumberFour has width 5).
   Each extract will be saved in a new file in Dir Extract
   Compare each character in the lists if they are identical. If they are valid then the extracted model will be saved in a file in Dir Validated with the name of a recognized Model name,
   and this file will be opened with Notepad for a few seconds, after which notepad will close and the search process will be repeated until the end of the List.
   The solutions to this approaches can be found [here](https://github.com/opreararesstefan/Recongnize_Text_Console)!